# Blank plots when jpeg() function parsed into a loop R

Tags: r, loops, plot, jpeg

Something strange happens when I parse plotting into a loop. All plots are saved but are entirely blank. `Seasons` is a vector and `AllYear_Avg` is a list. Both have the same length. No error is returned.

```
for (i in 1:length(Seasons)){
  jpeg(paste0(PathMap,Seasons[i],"AllYears.jpg"),res=300,width=10,height=13,units="cm")
  plt <- levelplot(AllYear_Avg[[i]] ~ lon * lat, 
                   xlim=c(-124.5,-114), ylim=c(32,42.5), 
                   data=grid, margin = F, at=cutpts, cuts=11, 
                   pretty=TRUE, par.settings = mapTheme,
                   col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("light blue","blue", "red")),
                   main=paste0(Var1description," \n",Seasons[i]," ",Yr))
  plt + layer(sp.lines(world.outlines.sp, col = "black", lwd = 0.5))
  dev.off()
}
```

In contrast, when I remove the top and bottom row and replace `[i]` with `[1]` (as can be seen below) it works fine and plot is saved as jpeg with a correct plot on it (not blank as in the loop). Is it possible to tell what is wrong with a loop above without a reproducible example?

```
jpeg(paste0(PathMap,Seasons[1],"AllYears.jpg"),res=300,width=10,height=13,units="cm")
plt <- levelplot(AllYear_Avg[[1]] ~ lon * lat, 
                 xlim=c(-124.5,-114), ylim=c(32,42.5), 
                 data=grid, margin = F, at=cutpts, cuts=11, 
                 pretty=TRUE, par.settings = mapTheme,
                 col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("light blue","blue", "red")),
                 main=paste0(Var1description," \n",Seasons[1]," ",Yr))
plt + layer(sp.lines(world.outlines.sp, col = "black", lwd = 0.5))
dev.off()
```

Comment: I think you need a `print(plt)` before `dev.off()`.

Comment: Thanks @zx8754 that was it!!